# Ideal way of sorting results by distance in Solr 4?

Tags: solr, geolocation, solr4

I'm trying hard to read and understand this document on spatial search in Solr 4:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4

But I'm having a hard time finding a simple answer: What is the ideal way of sorting results by distance in Solr 4?

I have two location fields available in my document set:

`geo` is a `location_rpt` field defined as:

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
    geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.000009" units="degrees" />
```

And `ll` is a location field defined as:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

The examples I'm seeing in the above referenced doc make reference to intersecting Circles and various things that don't seem necessary if all I'm interested in doing is providing a starting point (lat/lng) in my query, and getting a list of results sorted by distance.

**UPDATE:** The accepted answer provides a good solution that works in Solr 3 and 4. David Smiley's [comment on that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823077/ideal-way-of-sorting-results-by-distance-in-solr-4/15824987?noredirect=1#comment22530116_15824987) provides the strictly "Solr 4" way of doing a sort, for those interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to **Chapter 4 - Query Solr - Sorting Results by a distance from a point** in the *Apache Solr 4 Cookbook* in order to sort by distance against the  `ll` field you have defined in your schema, you would use the [geodist()](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geodist_-_The_distance_function) function like the following:

Assuming you are standing at the North Pole (0.0, 0.0) and you want to get the companies sorted in such a way that the ones that are nearer you are first in the results list. Your query would look like the following:

```
  http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=company&sort=geodist(ll,0.0,0.0)+asc
```

Comment: Thanks @PaigeCook. I was under the impression the my "ll" field was more of a Solr3 way if doing things, and my "geo" field was the Solr4 way of doing things. Are we still supposed to be using geodist in Solr4? The docs get confusing when they're talking about the old vs new spatial features.

Comment: The Solr 3 spatial fields support distance sorting better than the Solr 4 one, so Paige has the correct answer here for typical needs.  But you *need* the Solr 4 one if you have a variable number of points per document, since Solr 3 can't handle that.  The Solr 4 way of purely sorting (no filtering) is  &sort=query($sortsq) asc&sortsq={! score=distance filter=false}geo:"Intersects(Circle(54.729696,-98.525391 d=180))"  Notice the filter=false local-param, and the d=180 to effectively mean the whole world.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSmiley. I'm going to reference your comment in my original question to highlight this info.